# Batch file not executing a command

Tags: docker, batch-file, docker-container

I am trying to create a .bat file that will back-up the database inside the container. After the first command (that is used to enter the container) the next one is ignored.

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash
cd /var/opt/mssql/data
```

Any ideas why? If I'm trying to manually write `cd /var/opt/mssql/data` in the opened cmd it works.

Comment: `docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash -c 'cd /var/opt/mssql/data'` Where `-c` issues commands internal to the docker itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running `docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash`, you are opening a `bash`-shell INSIDE the docker container.

The next command, i.e. `cd /var/opt/mssql/data`, is only executed, if the previous command, `docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash` has exited successfully, which means that the shell on the docker container has been closed/exited.

This means that `cd /var/opt/mssql/data` is then executed on the local machine and not inside the docker container.

To run a command inside the docker container, use the following command

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash -c "<command>"
```

Although it may be better to create a script inside the container during the build process or mount a script inside the docker container while starting the container and then simply call this script with the above mentioned command.